# Find a number in a string after specific set of strings and characters

Tags: python, sql, regex, string, split

I am a python noob and am having trouble trying to extract a number. Its a SQL query, but i turned it into a string type. If there's a better way to do this, please let me know as well. My string contains many words that are similar, so I want to extract the number after a distinct set of words.

Example

```
{'first_name': 'Abigail', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'updated': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'account_id': '338502', 'created': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'student_id': '1730', 'notes': '', 'school_id': '16', 'major_id': '20', 'status': 'OPEN', 'id': '37'}
```

Out of this, I want to extract the "37" from they key "id". Store it in a variable

I tried it with .split(), but I am not sure that works because there are characters that don't work with the index because of the apostrophes and the colon. I know that there is a way to use SQL to get result (query.get('id')), but I want to know a way to extract this in a string.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Show here what you tried.

Comment: The above var type looks like a dictionary, you can just do `d.get('id')` to get its value.

Comment: I recommend you should read the data structures in python.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) - so you can simply access it by `set["id"]`

```
di = {'first_name': 'Abigail', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'updated': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'account_id': '338502', 'created': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'student_id': '1730', 'notes': '', 'school_id': '16', 'major_id': '20', 'status': 'OPEN', 'id': '37'}

print(di["id"])
```

Output:

```
37
```

Done.

If it is a string, you can split it into a dict like this:

```
di = "{'first_name': 'Abigail', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'updated': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'account_id': '338502', 'created': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'student_id': '1730', 'notes': '', 'school_id': '16', 'major_id': '20', 'status': 'OPEN', 'id': '37'}"

pairs = [x.replace("'","").strip("{}") for x in di.split(",")]
dic = dict( [ x.replace("'","").strip().split(":",1) for x in pairs] )
print(dic)
print(dic ["id"])
```

Output:

```
{'first_name': ' Abigail', 'last_name': ' Smith', 'updated': ' 2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'account_id': ' 338502', 'created': ' 2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'student_id': ' 1730', 'notes': '', 'school_id': ' 16', 'major_id': ' 20', 'status': ' OPEN', 'id': ' 37'}
 37
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ast module to convert string to dictionary

```
import ast
d="{'first_name': 'Abigail', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'updated': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'account_id': '338502', 'created': '2017-12-04 22:12:24.699-08', 'student_id': '1730', 'notes': '', 'school_id': '16', 'major_id': '20', 'status': 'OPEN', 'id': '37'}"
dic=ast.literal_eval(d)
print dic['id']
```

**Output**

```
37
```